# How Ubuntu kernel (3.12) did not trigger realtek 8169 issue?

Tags: kernel, realtek

I have a customized vanilla 3.12.14 kernel which could not work with r8169 ethernet card. Watchdog will through timeout on NETDEV error.

This error was reported on multiple distros, on 3.12 kernel. But none listed a solution.

Well, there is no issue on Ubuntu kernel (from kernel.ubuntu.com).

I am wondering which patch fixed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not state *which* version of ubuntu works for you, so I suppose it is the kernel which come with Saucy (13.10).

To see the kernel tree go to http:kernel.ubuntu.com, then choose git web. In the search box  put saucy and you will have a list of saucy kernel-related repository.

In https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide you see that the official kernel repo for Saucy is `ubuntu-saucy.git`. Choose this repo in the above list and then you can browse it.

For example, putting "r8169" in the commit search box you have something like that:

[image: gitweb]

Now you can browse here and see which patch(es) you need. Btw, if you have a launchpad issue, search for it; normally patches that fix some launchpad issue have the launchpad issue referenced in the commit, [like this one](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-saucy.git;a=commit;h=09b060f72a99799d98c6b632c764f51322b28675).

If you install git and take a copy of the tree(s) in your computer, [`git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)  is normally powerful enough to show you what is changed in the directory of the driver from two different versions. So you probably will be able (if you have the Ubuntu tree based on 3.12 --- don't know which one is) to restrict the commit diff to the two versions you're interested to.

Comment: Thank you. But I want patches applied to certain kernel version. For example, I checked 3.12.14 from kernel-ppa and no issue found. Thus I want to know what patches applied to this version compared to the original 3.12.14. Since the bug may not be fixed by patch to r8169 itself. Now I got Ubuntu-Trusty.git source, but cannot find tag labeled 3.12.14.

Comment: Probably kernel-ppa is a different tree... Ubuntu-saucy is 13.11 based I think. I don't know which bit tree is that one... Anyone here knows?